# Why parametric bootstrapping bias and standard error are zero here?

Tags: r, statistics, statistics-bootstrap

I'm performing parametric bootstrapping in `R` for a simple problem and getting `Bias` and `Standard Error` zero always. What am I doing wrong?

```
set.seed(12345)
df <- rnorm(n=10, mean = 0, sd = 1)

Boot.fun <- 
  function(data) {
    m1 <- mean(data)
    return(m1)
  }

Boot.fun(data = df)

library(boot)
out <- boot(df, Boot.fun, R = 20, sim = "parametric")
out
    PARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = df, statistic = Boot.fun, R = 20, sim = "parametric")


Bootstrap Statistics :
      original  bias    std. error
t1* -0.1329441       0           0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add line of code to do the sampling, ie.

```
Boot.fun <- 
    function(data) {
        data <- sample(data, replace=T)
        m1 <- ...
```

since you didn't supply a function to the argument `rand.gen` to generate random values.  This is discussed in the documentation for `?boot`.  If `sim = "parametric"` and you don't supply a generating function, then the original data is passed to `statistic` and you need to sample in that function.  Since your simulation was run on the same data, there is no standard error or bias.